# Journal style requires \@authors in uppercase

Tags: footnotes, titles

We are submitting an article to a journal which requires a camera-ready manuscript.  The format requires that the author block needs to be uppercase and the journal provides no style file.  So we're are trying to develop our own `.cls` file and are having difficulties.

The primary issue involves the inclusion of the `\footnote` or `\thanks` commands typically found in the preamble's `\author` command (for example, `\author{Arthur Pewtie \thanks{Chartered Accountancy Firm}}`).  Using `\MakeUppercase{\@author}` will cause errors like

```
 Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition
```

This can be avoided by hacking a `\protect` into the `\author` definition (`\author{Arthur Pewtie \protect\thanks{Chartered Accountancy Firm}}`) but then the `\MakeUppercase` in the `.cls` will uppercase the entire footnote.

We looked at `authblk` to help, but the closest that it can do is format the author block with small caps.

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.  We're looking, really, on solving this within the `.cls` file, rather than having authors provide a hack of the article fields within their `.tex` document.

Comment: Why not simply type the authors' names uppercase?

Comment: That is a possibility and is something that we will probably do in light of no program solution arising.  But doesn't that go against the intent of LaTeX to separate form from content?

Comment: I agree in general terms; but I'd bother with the problem if I had to write a class for managing the whole lot of journal submissions, not just one. If only there was an "all uppercase font"! ;-)

Comment: True.  I am doing it simply for our submission.  However, if it is clean enough, I would like to offer the `.cls` file to the journal so that they can hand it out to future submitters who are using LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution uses the [textcase](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/textcase/) package which modifies `\MakeUppercase` and provides a `\NoCaseChange` macro. I then redefine `\author` to use `\MakeUppercase` on its argument and `\thanks` to use `\NoCaseChange` on its argument. Due to the way the `\uppercase` macro works, I need to define a helper macro to do the wrapping of `\thanks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

\makeatletter
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\let\case@thanks\thanks
\def\thanks#1{\NoCaseChange{\case@thanks{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{My Name\thanks{Thanks to the little people}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat.  I didn't know about this package/approach.

Answer (score 2):

There's some trickery afoot.

OK, I'll share the secret.  Here is the logic:

1. I save copies of originally defined `\author` and `\thanks`.
2. I redefine `\author` as follows:

   a) I redefine `\thanks` to just save a copy of its argument into `ThanksText`.

   b) The `\setbox0` accomplishes placing the `\thanks` argument of `\author` into `\ThanksText`, without typesetting anything.

   c) Then I make the `\thanks` macro go away by redefining it as `{}` and throwing away its argument.

   d) I invoke the saved copy of `\author` with the following argument:

   - a `\MakeUppercase` of the original `#1`, except that the `\thanks` and its argument are thrown away, so that `\MakeUppercase` doesn't break; followed by
   - I check if `\ThanksText` is defined.  If so, I invoke the saved copy of `\thanks` using the `\ThanksText`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\svauthor\author
\let\svthanks\thanks
\def\author#1{%
  \def\thanks##1{\gdef\ThanksText{##1}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \def\thanks##1{}%
  \svauthor{%
    \MakeUppercase{#1}%
    \ifdef{\ThanksText}{\svthanks{\ThanksText}}{}}%
}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{My Name\thanks{Thanks to the little people}}
%\author{My Name}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]